# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I made a method that is supposed to clean up a `String`. It has to delete every char with a reach of `[a,z]`.

But I am getting this exception: `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
The moment I insert a number out of the reach of the conditions, this exception pops up.
I can't spot what I have done wrong.

```
    public static String kuisStringOp(String str){
        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder(str);

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if(strb.charAt(i)<'a'||strb.charAt(i)>'z'){

                strb.deleteCharAt(i);


            } 

        }           
        return strb.toString(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running through the entire length of your original string, but you are deleting some characters in your `StringBuilder`.  Once you've deleted a character, your `StringBuilder` is shorter than your original `String`, and the contents have shifted to cover the deleted character.  You'll eventually run off the end of the `StringBuilder` before you reach the end of your original `String`.

Change your `for` loop condition to check your `StringBuilder`'s length, and if you delete a character, another character is now in its place.  Check it again by decrementing `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strb.length(); i++) {
    if(strb.charAt(i)<'a'||strb.charAt(i)>'z'){
        strb.deleteCharAt(i);
        i--;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're to loop over `str` but delete from `strb`, you need
to keep two indexes/pointers, one to `str` and one to `strb`.

Try this.

```
public class Test015 {
    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
        String z = "111aaaa2222bbb";
        System.out.println(kuisStringOp(z));
    }

    public static String kuisStringOp(String str){
        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder(str);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if(strb.charAt(j)<'a'||strb.charAt(j)>'z'){
                strb.deleteCharAt(j);
            }else{
                j++;
            }
        }           
        return strb.toString(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
for (int i = 0; i < strb.length(); i++) {
```

as far as you deleting chars in buffer you need to check its length before the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the string and at the same time you are iterating over it ....

[Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would make a cleaner solution , like this:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "[a-z]", "");
```